# CSS block (div) background image and negative margin

Tags: html, css

has anyone got the bug on Opera (and others) but not IE6 (here everything is OK) when the block (DIV) has a background-image (no-repeat) does not appear if the block has negative margin? Something like this:

```
#slide_desc {height: 60px;margin-top: -84px;background: url('back/slide_desc.png') no-repeat;}
```

IE6, IE7 - OK
IE8, Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Safari - BUG
No background image no PNG hacks 
Just this HTML:

```
<div id="slider"> <img src="img/slide.jpg" height="300" width="730" border="0" /> <div id="slide_desc"> Lorem ipsum </div> </div>
```

and this CSS

```
#slide_desc {margin-top: -84px;background: url('slide_desc.png') no-repeat;}
```

If I add position: relative - works in Opera but doesn't work in IE6
If I change to position: fixed - everything is great but I'm not sure it's perfect way to solve the problem.
Becase of scrolling this scrolls too.

Comment: please show your whole css and the html for that - i don't think IE6 does anything right that opera and others don't - i'm sure theres a problem with your code and it's an IE bug to do what you want.

Comment: please edit your question to add information, writing this in comments is very confusing. i'll try to solve this when i'm at home if nobody has answered till then.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to give it a height and width or else it is only as big as the text in that div:

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VrEvA/

And another with the background in the original div:
http://jsfiddle.net/VrEvA/1/

Comment: but if it's not recommended to put slider image in background?

Comment: I don't understand what that means